# Extracting links from website with selenium bs4 and python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, grequests

Okay so.

The heading might seem like this question has already been asked but I had no luck finding an answer for it.

I need help with making link extracting program with python.

Actually It works. It finds all `<a>` elements on a webpage. Takes their `href=""` and puts it in an array. Then it exports it in `csv` file. Which is what I want.

But I can't get a hold of one thing.

The website is dynamic so I am using the Selenium webdriver to get JavaScript results.

The code for the program is pretty simple. I open a website with webdriver and then get its content. Then I get all links with

```
results = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
```

Then I loop through results with for loop and get `href` with

```
result.get_attribute("href")
```

I store results in an array and then print them out.

But the problem is that I can't get the name of the links.

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">This leads to Google</a>
```

Is there any way to get 'This leads to Google' string.

I need it for every link that is stored in an array.

Thank you for your time

**UPDATE!!!!!**

As it seems it only gets dynamic links. I just notice this. This is really strange now. For hard coded items, it returns an empty string. For a dynamic link, it returns its name.

Comment: I already tried that. But for some reason it returns a lot of empty strings but when I go in source code of website code exists. It also returns empty string for text that is not dyamic. I am testing it on website I made if you are wondering how I know that some data is not dynamic. It returns few strings but only like 20% of all.

Comment: Use result.get_attribute(‘innerHTML’) or result.get_attribute(‘textContent’) .Change the quotes it is tying by mobile device.

Comment: Thank you @KunduK. You saved me. I posted an answer to this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. So. The answer is that instad of using .text you shoud use get_attribute("textContent"). Works better than get_attribute("innerHTML")

Thanks KunduK for this answer. You saved my day :)